# linear-gradient only works for first line of text?

Tags: css

I'm using background: -webkit-linear-gradient() in conjunction with a few other styles (see below) to create gradient text in hero messages etc. The effect works great in every major desktop browser, except IE (and because of that I'm using the -webkit- prefixes to force the effect to only activate in webkit browsers and make IE fallback to the color style).

On iOS (tested on an up-to-date iPhone 8 Plus with both iOS Chrome and Safari), the effect only works for the first line. For example, in the following image I've highlighted where the words "your privacy" should appear.

[image example of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yd5E.jpg)

Here's the code:

```css
h1 {
    color: #5a6afe;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-75deg, #10C6FF, #7636FF, #10C6FF, #7636FF);
    background-size: 400%;
    animation: gradient 6s ease infinite;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

    @keyframes gradient {
        0% {background-position: 0% 50%;}
        50% {background-position: 100% 50%;}
        100% {background-position: 0% 50%;}
    }
```

```html
<h1>Committed to your privacy</h1>
```

What goes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix your `linear-gradient`s in different ways. For example, you need to use the `-webkit`, the `-moz` and just the standard version. Something like this:

```css
background: -o-linear-gradient(-75deg, #10C6FF, #7636FF, #10C6FF, #7636FF);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-75deg, #10C6FF, #7636FF, #10C6FF, #7636FF);
background: -webkit-gradient(-75deg, #10C6FF, #7636FF, #10C6FF, #7636FF);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-75deg, #10C6FF, #7636FF, #10C6FF, #7636FF);
background: linear-gradient(-75deg, #10C6FF, #7636FF, #10C6FF, #7636FF);
```

Also, iOS safari doesn't support `background-clip` with `background-size`, for some reason. According to caniuse.com:

> Partial support in Opera Mini refers to not supporting background sizing or background attachments. However Opera Mini 7.5 supports background sizing (including cover and contain values).
>
> Partial support in Safari 6 refers to not supporting background sizing offset from edges syntax

```css
h1 {
    color: #5a6afe;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-75deg, #10C6FF, #7636FF, #10C6FF, #7636FF);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-75deg, #10C6FF, #7636FF, #10C6FF, #7636FF);
    background: -webkit-gradient(-75deg, #10C6FF, #7636FF, #10C6FF, #7636FF);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-75deg, #10C6FF, #7636FF, #10C6FF, #7636FF);
    background: linear-gradient(-75deg, #10C6FF, #7636FF, #10C6FF, #7636FF);
    background-size: 400%;
    animation: gradient 6s ease infinite;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

    @keyframes gradient {
        0% {background-position: 0% 50%;}
        50% {background-position: 100% 50%;}
        100% {background-position: 0% 50%;}
    }
```

```html
<h1>Committed to your privacy</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! Since there's no support for {background-clip} with {background-size} when used together on iOS, I've broken each h1 up into multiple h1s stacked on top of each other. This allows me to keep using the gradient background.

And thanks for the -moz- prefixes. I've used your suggested edits but I've deleted the standard {background: linear-gradient} to force IE to fallback on the regular colored text.